# Get all articles belongs to subcategories ManyToMany Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, many-to-many

I'm trying to display all campaigns belongs to a parent category

[image]

**Category Model :**

```
   public function parents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category');
    }


    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','id','parent_id','categories');
    }


    public function campaigns()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Campaign' );
    }
```

**Campaign Model :**

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category' , 'campaign_category', 'campaign_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i just did this :D

```
    $campaigns = Campaign::whereHas('categories', function($q) use($id) {
        $q->where('parent_id', '=', $id);
    })->get();
```